# Qual a diferença entre wamp bitnami e wampserver?

Tags: wamp, wampserver, bitnami

https://bitnami.com/stack/wamp
http://www.wampserver.com/

Vem com mais componentes ou é a mesma coisa?

Comment: please use english to asking questions

Answer (score 2):

Bitnami WAMP and wampserver are different products. In the case of Bitnami WAMP we bundle the following components:

- Apache
- MySQL
- PHP
- PHPMyAdmin
- ImageMagick
- SQLite
- ModSecurity
- Git
- Zend Framework
- Symfony
- CodeIgniter
- CakePHP
- Smarty
- Laravel

Plus, we offer WAMP modules for several web applications such as Wordpress, Joomla!, Drupal... amongst others.

Wampserver also offers its components apart from Apache, MySQL and PHP, namely phpMyAdmin, phpsysinfo... therefore you can try both and see which satisfies your needs better.